# Docker stack gives failed state but the container shows up

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have the below output when I do a docker stack ps command, which shows two tasks

```
docker stack ps my_docker_stack
ID             NAME                                            IMAGE                                                          NODE             DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE          ERROR                         PORTS
1234567890   mine_transform_integration.1       eu.gcr.io/my-prj-development-x001/mine_transform_integration:0.1.1   my-node-01   Running         Running 2 months ago
76890123456    \_ mine_transform_integration.1   eu.gcr.io/my-prj-development-x001/mine_transform_integration:0.1.1   my-node-01   Shutdown        Failed 2 months ago    "task: non-zero exit (137)"
```

As you see one id shows it should be in shutdown as desired state.

```
docker inspect 76890123456

"Status": {
            "Timestamp": "",
            "State": "failed",
            "Message": "started",
            "Err": "task: non-zero exit (137)",
            "ContainerStatus": {
                "ContainerID": "cvghjkjhjkl",
                "PID": 12789,
                "ExitCode": 0
            },
            "PortStatus": {}
        },
        "DesiredState": "shutdown",
```

However If i check the container status with the id from the above output

```
docker ps | grep 'cvghjkjhjkl'

mine_transform_integration.1.76890123456  up
```

It shows up. Should nt this be down as the desired state is shutdown? How do i refresh docker swarm so that it will be in failed state?Is this expected?